# Is this the right order to clear SqlDataAdapter and Sql Command Parameters and close the connection?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and C# , I am using windows forms C#.

As shown in the example code, is this the correct order of clearing SqlDataAdapter and clearing Sql Command Parameters and closing the connection?

Please guide me. Thank you

```
public partial class C1 : UserControl
{
    SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand();

    DataTable DataTable = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter Sql_Data_Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

    public C1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataTable.Rows.Clear();
        DataTable.Columns.Clear();

        MyConnection.Open();

        MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM taqble1";
        MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

        Sql_Data_Adapter.SelectCommand = MyCommand;
        Sql_Data_Adapter.Fill(DataTable);

        buttonMD1_1.Text = Convert.ToString(DataTable.Rows[0]["Button_Text"]);
        buttonMD1_2.Text = Convert.ToString(DataTable.Rows[1]["Button_Text"]);
        buttonMD1_3.Text = Convert.ToString(DataTable.Rows[2]["Button_Text"]);
        buttonMD1_4.Text = Convert.ToString(DataTable.Rows[3]["Button_Text"]);

        // I did not clear DataTable because later I will use it
        MyCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        Sql_Data_Adapter.Dispose();
        MyConnection.Close();           
    }
```

Comment: I'd rather us a [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). it will close and dispose of your db objects for you.

Comment: a side note...datatables are meant to work disconnected, so you are on the right path. Open connection, command, keep them open just long enough to fill your structure, then disconnect and use the data retrieved elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The order of distruction of your objects is not too important here, the important thing is to avoid global variables and be sure to always dispose the disposable objects

```
public C1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    using(SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(...))
    using(SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM taqble1", MyConnection))
    using(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(MyCommand))
    {
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         adapter.Fill(dt);
         .... button code ....
    }
}
```

The [Using Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) closes and dispose the disposable objects also in case of Exceptions. The DataTable object is local, so when the code exits (and you don't need it anymore) it will be automatically disposed.

Avoid keeping a global object for the connection, there is a [Connection Pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx) infrastructure that allows to get good performance in using this kind of object. The SqlCommand is lightweight and it is easily rebuilt when you need it, the SqlDataAdapter instead is meant to be reused for updating when you bind the DataTable to a grid, so sometimes is necessary to keep it global.
In your context, I think you should simply use a SqlDataReader instead of an SqlDataAdapter

```
public C1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    using(SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(...))
    using(SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM taqble1", MyConnection))
    {
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         using(SqlDataReader reader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader())
         {
            dt.Load(reader);
            .... button code ....
         }
    }
}
```

I see a lot of time this kind of error, in particular around the connection object. People thinks to get better performances keeping it global. That's not true and both your local and remote resources are stressed with a global connection object.

Comment: ... which of course nicely enforces the correct order of disposal as well, since now you have the correct scoping.

Comment: I also agree with your statement that he should use a reader instead of a adapter but it would be nice to include the syntax to load a data table directly from a `SqlDataReader` in the answer.